# Force windows to communicate to specific ip addresses via specific network card

Tags: windows, networking, routing, lan, tcp

Hello I'm currently facing issues with tcp communication on a windows 10 system with two network cards.
I need to connect specific hardware which is in a LAN.
Sometimes windows uses the network adapter which is connected to the LAN sometimes it uses the other one which is used for internet access.

Now I want to to force windows that for two specific ip-addresses only a specific adapter will be used.
Is there a way to do this?

Already added the ip-addresses via the route add command what sadly does not make any difference.

Here is a picture of the routing table.
The ip-addresses with the problem are the ones in the red square.

[Route table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLUgm.png)

Adding a Firewall entry for the Ip-Addresses does not change the bevavior either. I'm just getting a different error message.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Your routes overlap. Try to give the LAN rules a low metrics so they have priority.

Comment: @harrymc giving it a lower metrics doesn't change the behavior sadly. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: Maybe adding a routing table rule? See https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/?

Comment: Your routes might overlap, but that is not clear from the description. Please add which subnets you have on each of the interfaces, what specific IP addresses you are trying to reach, and possibly a printout of the routing table.

Comment: @Paul just added the screenshot of the routing table. I want to reach 192.168.222.1 and 192.168.222.2

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't tell me much with all the relevant information blacked out. Hint: showing local (192.168.x.x) addresses is not a privacy risk.

Comment: @Paul just updated it again

Comment: your routes are actually identical. The persistent routes for 192.168.222.1 and 192.168.222.2 should have a netmask of 255.255.255.255, if your want to create exceptions for specific addresses.

Comment: @Paul sorry for the late replay but the issue still occurs with subnet mask 255.255.255.255 in the route :(